# Capybara Webkit installation

Tags: rubygems, capybara-webkit, ruby-2.3

Hey all this is my first project in ruby and I am trying to install capybara using the the instructions here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

I keep running into this error constantly. Any help is appreciated.

```
Windows 10
Ruby 2.3
Qt 5.9.1

PATH has C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2015_64\bin and C:\Ruby23\bin


current directory: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0
C:/Ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170817-33208-1eyrgjv.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You 
may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby23/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-gl-dir
--without-gl-dir
--with-gl-include
--without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
--with-gl-lib
--without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.9.1 doesn't include the needed QtWebkit by default, so you'd need to install that.  Look in `mkmf.log` as the error message instructs and see exactly what is missing.

That being said, capybara-webkit is based on tech which is currently equivalent to, at best, a 7 year old browser, and therefore doesn't support a lot of stuff used in modern apps.  You will probably be a lot better off if you don't use capybara-webkit and instead use Capybara with selenium and headless chrome.

Clarification note:  capybara-webkit is not capybara, it's a driver that can be used with capybara.

Comment: Turns out the Gemfile was not configured correctly OR it is part of the test that I am doing. Thanks for your prompt reply in any case.